# Assign part of a line plot a specific color in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, appearance

I have the following graph

[image]

They fluctuate if a value `v=1`. `PB1`->`PB4` can fluctuate simultaneuously if `v1`->`v4` is also equal to 1.
I want visualise the process where any of the variables `PB1`->`PB4` are fluctuating because  of `v` by colouring them red.

Is this possible in Matlab ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "because of the same specific number". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @pancake question updated

Comment: I suspect that this is possible, but you'll need to show the code that generates that plot. You'll need to calculate where the variables are fluctuation due to v and plot those ranges separately.

Comment: I think I tried to do something like this and couldn't find a good solution. My suggestion is to break up your data for x>=1 and x<1 and then plot them separately on the same graph using `hold on`between plotting commands